# Codeigniter can not find the view file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a beginner with the codeigniter, I am trying to render the view file but Codeigniter is not getting the view file.

**My Controller Fucntion**

```
public function index()
{
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->getNews();
    $data['title'] = 'Todas as noticias';

    $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer', $data);
}
```

**My Routing**

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['default_controller'] = 'news';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

Can anyone figure out what's wrong i have done here ?

Comment: did you save your index.php file inside view/news folder

Comment: Yes is inside the news folder

Comment: sorry my fault its is working right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routes.php file just remove  `$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';` . CodeIgniter has automatic routing system. You dont need to specify it. It is like  `example.com/class/function/ID`.

In your case, you can access index function of news controller by typing `http://localhost/yourprojectname` (since it is your default controller) or by typing `http://localhost/yourprojectname/index.php/news`.

Remember you can also remove index.php from your url by using .htaccess file.
In your .htaccess file copy and paste following line and save it in your project directory

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
class  news extends CI_Controller() {
public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $data['news'] = $this->news_model->getNews();
    $data['title'] = 'Todas as noticias';
}

public function index() {
    $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('news/index', $data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer', $data);
}
}
```

Add base_url in config file :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/folder_name/';
```

To remove index.php file add file `.htaccess` in root folder and copy following code to that file :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And remove the code from your routes.php :

```
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
```